# Looking for some ideas on how to create an custom shirt designing like tailorstore

Tags: reactjs, three.js, jquery-plugins, hammer.js

Looking for recommendation to create a custom shirt designing feature like the website [tailorstore.co.in](https://www.tailorstore.co.in/shirt-designer#lHf1H4sA5Ce48bKPGs0qC9eGLUmfvsDl) (CUSTOMIZING SHIRT).

While exploring, i thoughts like they might:

```
1. Created 3D models and generated n-number of combinations.

- Because the shirt pictures were too accurate.
```

```
2. Used HAMMER.JS, THREEJS.ORG, REACT.JS to bring such a accurate feel.

- While reference their source codes.
```

```
3. Did some photo shoots and used in the website.

- Tried to convince myself.
```

But i couldn't jump into any conclusion, so i came here to know your opinion on this.

Any guidance on this is highly appreciable.  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Without going deep down to technicism, your stack seems appropriate.
I only suggest you to use a wrapper for library like `hammer.js` like `react-hammerjs`.
About `ThreeJS`: I've tried many wrappers, may be is better to build your own, I can provide examples if needed.

Comment: I checked some examples to understand hammer.js.  But it doesnt add up.
Will really appreciate your help @mosè-raguzzini

Comment: @Raaj, what example is not clear in hammer.js docs ? have you checked react-hammerjs ?

Comment: i checked this [link](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-hammerjs).  I was wondering like how did the actual website acheived that shirt customization image with this Tappable - Events.

Comment: when i tried to analyze the customization part.  I got an concept that, they might used some 3D template to create images of product with different views and called it using tappable react-hammer.js.

Comment: hmhm hammer.js is used to manage gestures, but gestures are already managed by threeJS by third party implementations like http://mese79.github.io/TouchControls/. What you have to do for the core of your system is creating a 3d model for every shape of t-shirt that you plan to sell, create a material (optional, this is if you want a more accurate preview) for each material you plan to use for t-shirt, then create a set of texture for each type of picture you plan to put on your t-shirts. Mix those elements and you'll get a t-shirt configurator.

Comment: thanks @mosè-raguzzini, will work out and share my results.  It might help fellow aspirants...

Comment: i found a tool to generate images for all views and stages.  Then used JSON to display the selected images.  Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @Raaj Im facing the same issue, could you please share your solution